# PostgresSql error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

i am running this query where in rel_branding there are more than 1 rows and i want to insert brandingid of every record in rel_branding_permission.

This is for PostgresSQL.

```
insert into rel_branding_permission (brandingid,permissionid) 
values((select brandingid from rel_branding), 404);
```

I want to insert this query in my DB as for all branding ids

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` here, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO rel_branding_permission (brandingid)
SELECT brandingid
FROM rel_branding
WHERE <some condition>
```

You would probably want to include more than one column in the insert into the `rel_branding_permission` table, and you may modify the above to fit your need by adding the additional columns to both the `INSERT` and the `SELECT`.